# Building an ALU on nandgame's website

Tags: logic, arithmetic, cpu, digital-circuits

I'm working on nandgame's website found [here](http://nandgame.com/). I'm working on the ALU and here is an image of my implementation:

*My Implementation:*

[image]

And I compared it to [this](https://github.com/simsieg/nandgame-solutions/blob/master/solutions/19_ALU.png) website's solution:

*Solution*

[image]

---

However when I try to submit this... The website gives me this message and error:

[image]

And for the life of me, I don't see where any of the connections are misplaced... Maybe a second set of eyes might help...

**Edit**

I even tried the solution from this website:[programmersought](https://programmersought.com/article/34101285843/) and I still can't seem to get it to accept it as being correct... It's giving me the same exact error message as above. Could this be a potential bug on the website app?

I even posted this issue to Github's solution page found [here](https://github.com/simsieg/nandgame-solutions/issues/3) regarding this...

Comment: I don't know where else or which stack site to ask this question, and I was thinking that this was the most appropriate. If it isn't please don't hesitate to point me in the right direction. Also, if the tags don't seem to be appropriate please give useful advice for proper tags. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's like a typo, but in a picture: you have two adders but it should be an adder and an "and" block (what's the point of two adders that compute the same thing, right?)

Comment: @harold thanx for pointing that out... I was overlooking it for hours... that's why you need a second set of eyes sometimes!